# How to make a setTimeout script work properly with an html form?

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, ajax, forms

This is the script:

```
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.11.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
    <script>
                function addedCart() {
      document.getElementById("msgs-box").innerHTML = "Item added successfully to cart";
      setTimeout(function() {
        $('#msgs-box').html('');
      }, 6000);
    }
               </script>
```

The form:

```
<form action="addToCart" method="post">
<input name="productId" value="${product.id}" type="hidden">
<input class="submit" onclick="addedCart()" value="<fmt:message key='AddToCart'/>" type="submit">
</form>
```

The issue:

When I put `type="submit"` and click on `"addToCart"`, the script is fired and the message displays but the time isn't working. Whether I put 3 secs (3000) or 30 secs (30 000) as time value, the script will not play the time right. The message will just appear and disappear.

On the other hand, When I put `type="button"` and click on `"addToCart"`, the script is fire, the message displays and the script is playing the time right **but** the values aren't sent to the `cart.jsp`.

How can I solve this issue? I need to send the values to the cart and I need the script to work and play the time right.

## Edit --- The New Code With Ajax

```
    var $msgBox = $('#msgs-box');

function addedCart() {

    event.preventDefault(); // Prevent default Form Submit Action

    $msgBox.html("Item added successfully to cart");
    setTimeout(function() {
        $msgBox.html('');
    }, 6000);

    $.ajax({
       url : 'cart.jsp',
       data: $("#cartForm").serialize(), // (tip: assign and use an ID for your form)
       success: function( addedCart ) {
         alert( "Item added successfully to cart", addedCart);
       }
    });

}
```

The HTML:

```
<form id="cartForm" action="addToCart" method="post">
              <br>
              <br>

              <input name="productId" value="${product.id}" type="hidden">
              <input class="submit" onclick="addedCart()" value="<fmt:message key='AddToCart'/>" type="submit">
```

Comment: Adding a timer doesn't prevent the form from submitting. When the form submits, the page reloads. But if you prevent the form submitting, the values don't get sent to the server. Search google for "submit form with ajax", sounds like that's what you're after.

Comment: I think @ChristianVarga is right. You want an ajax submit. gl hf

Answer (score 1):

Your form, cause of the `type="submit"` input is getting submitted, triggering request, following headers etc...
To prevent that, simply access the `event` and prevent it from triggering default actions:

```
var $msgBox = $('#msgs-box');

function addedCart() {

    event.preventDefault(); // Prevent default Form Submit Action

    $msgBox.html("Item added successfully to cart");
    setTimeout(function() {
        $msgBox.html('');
    }, 6000);

    // Send data to server with AJAX here...

}
```

Since now the form data **isn't yet submitted**, you can use AJAX to forward your serialized `data` to your server.

An example would be:

```
    // Send data to server with AJAX here...
    $.ajax({
       url : 'addToCartHandler.php',
       data: $("form").serialize(), // (tip: assign and use an ID for your form)
       success: function( response ) {
         alert( "This is my php response: "+ response );
       }
    });
```

Comment: If I understand well: 

`$.ajax({
       url : 'cart.jsp',
       data: $("cartForm").serialize(),
       success: function( response ) {
         alert( "Item added successfully to cart" );
       }
    });`

Correct...?

Comment: I think I must of done something wrong... With your new code, the data is being sent to the server but the message box isn't displaying at all... Please see the edit for full code.

Comment: @user23524697 `$("cartForm")` where's the ID `#` ??

Comment: @user23524697 so what's your issue now? it looks quite good now.

Comment: The message doesn't display... `:$`

Comment: @user23524697 open console (hit F12 to open the Developer Tools) and read what errors are thrown.